# Finding the absolute minimum of $f(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)^{1/2} *e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I made the substitution $x=r\cos(\theta)$ , $y =r\sin(\theta)$. And I obtained $re^{-r^2}$. I then used the first derivative test to obtain $r=+-1/(2^{1/2})$. Is this right?

Comment: Points that satisfy zero gradient are any of the following possibilities: local maximum/minimum or a saddle point. In your case, only $r = 2^{-1/2}$ makes sense as a stationary point. We check and find that $f'(r) = (1-2r)e^{-r^2}$ and $f''(r) = (-2r-2+4r^2)e^{-r^2}$, where we evaluate this at $r= 2^{-1/2}$ and get $-2r<0$ and so it is a local maximum. Checking the boundary conditions, namely $r=0$ and $r \rightarrow \infty$, we find that $f$ vanishes. This implies that the absolute minimum is $0$.

Comment: I forgot to include that the region is all of r2

Comment: @chris k what do you mean by boundary conditions

Comment: Well... $r$ can be no smaller than $0$ ($g(r)$ is not differentiable here) and we still need to check the limit at infinity. Consider $g(x,y) = \exp(-(x^2+y^2))$ or equivalently $g(r) = \exp(-r^2)$. Then $g'(r) = -2r\cdot \exp(-r^2) = 0$ iff $r = 0$. This is a global maximum. However, in the limiting case, $g(r) \rightarrow 0$. So $0$ would be a local **infimum** (greatest lower bound) for $g$.

Comment: Explain why g(r) is not differentiable below 0

Comment: The point is that $r$ is between $0$ and $\infty$. A two-sided derivative of $g(r)$ is not defined at $r = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function being the product of two non-negative quantities is non-negative. Since f(0,0)=0, 0 is the absolute minimum and is attained at (0,0). As is written in many books, "it is left to the reader to verify that there can be no other absolute mimima."